# Hooks in cucumberJs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, bdd, cucumberjs

I am using cucumberJS with Request package to test my web APIs. In cucumberJS I want to use different kind of hooks. [Reference](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md) - Here I see only Before and After hooks. Specifically I look for a hook to handle actions before my test execution starts (simillar to onPrepare - in protractor). Please help me !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [event handlers](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/1.x/docs/support_files/event_handlers.md). With the `event handler` you can prepare your environment before:

- all features
- a feature
- a scenario
- a step

I'm also wondering what you exactly want to do with the preparation, because the `onPrepare` in protractor is only a thing that can handle methods when the browser is already active, but the tests are not executed.

If you want to prepare you environment before all tests start you can or have a different (npm) script that will do this for you before the cucumber script is run, or when you use protractor, use a `beforeLaunch` function.

Comment: I wanted to assign few global variables like  `global.expect = chai.expect;`
`global.environment = appConfig.t1b;` before my test starts. Thanks !!!

Comment: You are welcome, did it also help? And if so, can you share your solution in your question so everybody can learn from it?

Comment: Live example: https://testjam.io/?p=6s0O9gKZfWl4odC8h5t2